# How to turn off --classify option in ls command?

Tags: ls

My ls command is aliased to have certain options automatically applied, including --classify (same as -F)  Normally this is fine and I don't want to screw around with my .bashrc file.

Just this one time, I want to turn off --classify but don't see how even after reading the info page and some googling.   There's no --classify=none or --classify=off or --no-classify or anything else I could guess.

This is on Red Hat linux in a bash shell.

Comment: Check to see if you specified an alias for ls in your .profile ? Perhaps you set `alias ls="ls --classify"` in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn off `--classify` selectively by using `--indicator-style=none`:

```
$ alias  lc='ls --classify --color=auto'
$ lc -ld foo bar baz
drwxr-xr-x 6 user group  4096 2010-07-19 09:09 foo/
-rwxr--r-- 1 user group 19035 2010-09-30 17:39 bar*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group    26 2010-11-29 00:44 baz
$ lc -ld --indicator-style=none foo bar baz
drwxr-xr-x 6 user group  4096 2010-07-19 09:09 foo
-rwxr--r-- 1 user group 19035 2010-09-30 17:39 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group    26 2010-11-29 00:44 baz
```

Comment: Where Unix is, there is always a clean solution: Thanks for providing it!

Comment: Changed this to the best answer, the one true way.  The backslash or single-quotes does work, but remove all the options in the alias, some of which I continue to want.   This --indicator-style option, assuming I will remember it, neatly turns off just the one thing I want off.  Very nice!

Answer (score 8):

After defining an alias, it remains possible to ask bash to use the unaliased command when necessary, using one of the following syntaxes:

```
$ 'ls'
$ \ls
```

Others tips (howto remove it, etc) about the `alias` command
are available in the [dedicated "alias" Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29)

Comment: This solves my immediate problem, thanks!  But it would still be nice to know how to turn off only one of several options set by the alias.

Comment: If you know that the `ls` command is an alias, you can remove unwanted option temporarly by dynamicaly generating the "cleaned" `ls` command using the return of a sed: `$(alias ls | cut -f2 -d'=' | sed 's/-l//') myrep` to remove a `-l`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily disable aliases by using a \ with the command.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-temporarily-disable-an-alias/

Answer (score 0):

You could re-alias it with whatever options you want, and it would be reset to whatever is in your .bashrc file on your next session.

Comment: I don't want the one-time (or three-time, since I make mistakes) modification to the options to last beyond the immediate use.